# Launch my Google Action from the Android App

Tags: android, xamarin, google-assistant-sdk

I've been trying for some days to open the google assistant with one button (done) and sending a query to open my google action (not done). This seems impossible so far. Any help? Btw, I am using Xamarin, but android answers are very welcomed too.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionVoiceCommand);

        String queryString = "Talk to my google action";
        intent.SetClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox",
                            "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.SearchActivity");
        intent.PutExtra("query", queryString);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you wouldn't send a text-based query to search. Rather, in the Actions Console you will see [Action Links](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/action-links).

For a given Action, you will see the **Links** section. When you enable it, you will be given an HTML code snippet that you can use on a website or even in an Android app.

`https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/<action-id>?hl=en`

You can use this URL in your Android app by opening it. This will trigger the Assistant to capture the URL and open your Action.

```
String url = "https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/<action-id>?hl=en";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?
[image]

I change the `Intent.ActionVoiceCommand` to `Intent.ActionWebSearch`

Here is my code.

```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionWebSearch);
        intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
        string queryString = "Talk to my google action";
        intent.SetClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox",
                            "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.SearchActivity");
        intent.PutExtra("query", queryString);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        StartActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: The real idea is that I want to open my google action in the google assistant, not look for it in the web searcher.